# How you can take down copyrighted content in Telegram?

Tags: copyright, dmca

Suppose that a content creator C has posted video courses and other online content for which fees are charged. Several Telegram channels and bots are posting these videos without C's authorization and causing significant financial harm to C. How can C close those channels? Suppose that C has already tried contacting dmca@telegram.org but did not get any responses.

Comment: I found this article useful about the whole process and ended up using their services: https://medium.com/@elisajtelegramdmca/how-to-submit-dmca-in-telegram-and-protect-your-copyright-cb8fb60d37c

Comment: this ones look legit? https://www.pellonia.io/

Answer (score 3):

The takedown process is explained in detail [here](https://copyrightalliance.org/education/copyright-law-explained/the-digital-millennium-copyright-act-dmca/dmca-notice-takedown-process/#:%7E:text=The%20DMCA%20Takedown%20Process,infringing%20their%20copyright(s).&text=It%20should%20not%20be%20used%20for%20anything%20other%20than%20copyright%20infringement%20claims.). If you do not get a response from the ISP or hosting firm within the time allowed, you can bring suit against both the offender (if known) and Telegram in federal court, because failing to honor takedown notices forfeits Telegram's Section 230 immunity from liability under the Digital Millennium Copyright Act.

Comment: Note that to bring suit in a US court over a US work, the work must have its copyright registered first.

Comment: @DavidSiegel True but straightforward to accomplish relative to the overall task of filing a lawsuit.

Comment: Yes, but it seems to be overlooked with some frequency, so I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I don't disagree. Thanks for the contribution.